# ExtJS 6 - Issue while adding new items to accordion panel

Tags: extjs, extjs5, extjs6

I have a new `ExtJS 6` application and Im trying to populate an accordion menu.

Note: This same code works perfect in `ExtJS 4.2`.

This is the accordion component:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.menu.Accordion', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainmenu',
    width: 350,
    split: true,
    layout: {
        type: 'accordion',
        autoScroll: true,
        autoHeight: true,
        titleCollapse: false,
        animate: false,
        activeOntop: true
    },
    collapsible: true,
    floatable: false,
    hideCollapseTool: false,
    title: 'Menú',
});
```

Now, I have in my ViewController a store that I load, this is the code:

```
var menuPanel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('mainmenu')[0];


storeMenu.load({
    callback: function(records, op, success) {

        menuPanel.removeAll();


        Ext.each(records, function(rec) {


            var title = rec.data.title;


            var menu = Ext.create({
                xtype: 'treepanel',
                rootVisible: false,
                title: 'This is a test'
            });


            menuPanel.add(menu);


        });

        menuPanel.updateLayout();
    }
});
```

My store records count = 7, so I should see 7 items added to my menu, but this is what I get:

[image]

If I again do the same but adding a breakpoint in my debuggin console (image below)

[image]

Then my result is the following:

[image]

> The issue is breaking my head and is really very strange, it works if I debugg adding a breakpoint in order it to work.

Any clue on this issue?

Comment: in the first section of code, you're adding menu2, but in the debugging code it's just menu. maybe browser cache has old copy?

Comment: Sorry was a typo here, just updated the question.

Comment: maybe try removing the call to menuPanel.updateLayout(). i don't think you need to call that, and it looks like maybe it's getting executed before the stuff in Ext.each.

Comment: I remove it and is the same behavioir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding them in one call:

```
storeMenu.load({
    callback: function(records, op, success) {
        var panels;

        Ext.suspendLayouts();
        menuPanel.removeAll();

        panels = Ext.Array.map(records, function(rec){
          var title = rec.get('title');

          return {
            xtype: 'treepanel',
            rootVisible: false,
            title: title
          };
        });

        menuPanel.add(panels);  
        Ext.resumeLayouts(true);
    }
});
```